# How can select a particular list element in javascript. To change its style?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I want to change style of a particular li item when it is clicked how can I do that?

Comment: Please provide html code

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You could add an event listener for a click event, then add CSS for that particular `li`.

## Vanilla JS

```js
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    item.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  });
})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>world!</li>
  <li>Filler</li>
</ul>
```

## jQuery:

```js
$('li').click(function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>world!</li>
  <li>Filler</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a extra class on your styles and a bit of javascript,
Here is a demo:

```js
const list = document.querySelectorAll('.listItem');

list.forEach(item => 
  item.addEventListener('click', e => e.target.classList.add('clicked') )
);
```

```css
.listItem {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.clicked {
    background: white;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="listItem">Click me</li>
    <li class="listItem">Or me</li>    
</ul>
```

There are more ways but this seems easy and understandable.